Backpressure in NodeJS
I want to read data from CSV which is pretty large and then push that data into postgres and we are using drizzle orm.
I am trying to read data by creating a fs.readStream and then pipe the data to csv_parse as I just want to insert 1 column.
The issue I am facing is that back-pressure is created as writing the data to DB is taking time hence my code crashes giving
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Here is my code -
const readStream = createReadStream(
    "file_name.csv"
  )
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }))
    .on("data", async (row) => {
      await addDataToDB(row[2]);
    });
};

I tried reading data from csv using stream and then adding data to DB. But it failed as backpressure is generated.

You can use a batch size and pause the stream during processing. Ex:
const BATCH_SIZE = 100; 


async function processBatch(batch) {
  try {
    await addDataToDB(batch);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error inserting data into DB:", err);
  }
}

const readStream = createReadStream("file_name.csv")
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }));

let batch = [];

readStream.pause();

readStream.on("data", async (row) => {
  batch.push(row[2]);

  if (batch.length >= BATCH_SIZE) {
    await processBatch(batch);
    batch = [];
    readStream.resume();
  }
});

readStream.on("end", async () => {
  if (batch.length > 0) {
    await processBatch(batch);
  }
  console.log("CSV processing complete.");
});

readStream.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Error reading CSV file:", err);
});

